# How to Set Custom Properties of SSIS Components using Script Task

Tags: ssis

I am using a custom "Connection Manager" that talks to a proprietary database. One of the fields in the Custom Properties section of this object is called "DataQuery", where you can define a query that will be executed on the other end.

I want to use the ScriptTask to build a SQL query on the fly using some variables that are passed in, some c# logic, etc.

Problem is while I know how to set a variable in the script task, I am not sure of the syntax (or if its possible) to set a custom property value.

Some, psuedo code would be:

```
MyConnectionManager.Properties["DataQuery"] = myQueryString;
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have more information on the custom connection manager - generally queries are not part of the connection manager itself.

Perhaps you can :

Use the script task to assign the custom query to a variable.

In the properties of the custom connection string expand expressions

Find the "Dataquery" under properties

Under the corresponding expression use the variable you created in the script task

OR

choose the Connectionstring property and build the connections string as an expression using the variable created in the script task

Comment: OK, to clarify a little, there are really two pieces. There is a "Data Flow Source" item called "Geneva Source" (this is for connecting to Geneva, a 3rd party accounting system). There is a Connection Manager element to that where you specify server, port, uname, pw, etc. Then in the Geneva Source component, there are tabs you would expect (Connection Managers, Component Properties, Column Mappings, Inout and Output Properties). The Component Properties has two sections: Common Properties and Custom Properties. It is within this custom properties section that the "GenevaQuery" property exists

Comment: If I try to set the value of this property to a variable, it throws an error saying that the query syntax is invalid. SSIS does not seem to be properly substituting the variable with a value, it simply sends the variable syntax in to Geneva which of course fails. So I was hoping there would be a way I could set this property in script.

Comment: Under the actual GenevaConnectionManager component, I do see the expressions, and you can set the username, pw, connectionstring, etc. dynamically. But ... I do not see any way to get at the GenevaQuery proeprty or any expressions option under the custom connection string.